# RemoteWebDriver & IE8 hangs Downloading picture res://ieframe.dll/background_gradient_red.jpg

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I've managed to handle a missing security certificate in IE8, however quite often the browser will hang while loading "Downloading picture res://ieframe.dll/background_gradient_red.jpg..." and any following IE tests on the node fail also.

I'm working with the ops team to fix the certificate issue, but in the meantime has anyone else seen this problem?

In case it helps here is how I'm creating the driver...

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.HandlesAlerts,true);
capabilities.SetCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings",true);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(GridHubUrl), capabilities);
driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

And this bit handles clicking override...

```
public static void Handle()
    {
        if (driver.ToString() == "OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver" ||
            driver.Url.Contains("res://ieframe.dll/invalidcert.htm"))
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I faced the same issue, but resolved by doing this-

### Browser setting:

In your browser go to:
**Settings-> Internet Options->Security-> Trusted Sites ->"Sites" button -> Add your site**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\Desktop\\selenium jars\\Eclipse Jars\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.29.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

driver.get(baseUrl + "/content/");
    driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
    driver.findElement(By.id("edit-acct")).clear();
```